# Primefaces TreeTable - how to get the index of the selected node?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, tree

I'm working with the primefaces treetable and I'm trying to create buttons on each row so that a user can reorder the elements in a tree table.

For example, if i have a tree table with 3 nodes all at the same level, and each of those three nodes in the treetable has an "Up" button, if the up button is clicked on one of the nodes, I want that node to move up (basically reorder the nodes).

How can i get the index of of the selected node?

```
for(int i = 0; i < selectedNode.getParent().getChildren().size(); i++) {

    // how can i compare the index of the current child in the loop to the selected child?
}
```

Comment: Create a custom class extending `TreeNode` having an index?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clean, but you could

1. Using the `selection` attribute on the table, get a handle on the selected node in your backing bean and then
2. Using the `indexOf` method on your backing (i'm assuming) `List`, get the index of the item. The order of dynamically generated databound items of primefaces generally follows the index/ordering of backing collections, so you can trust the indexing.

Alternatively, you could try the `<p:ajax/>` component to set the selected option and do as above.

Answer (score 0):

U can get selected node index using the method "getRowKey()"

Perhaps:

```
selectedNode.getRowKey()
```

And, if U want count nodes size U can to use method "getChildCount()", perhaps:

```
selectedNode.getParent().getChildCount()
```